# accept POST from only own server

Tags: php, .htaccess, post

i have developed a project in PHP now i need to process those POST DATA which have been sent from my own server !
how to do it ?
REFERRER is not a solution, as it can be blocked/removed or changed easily !
is there code to stop it in **.htaccess** ?

Comment: There is no way to enforce this. You could add a challenge to the page, but that can be retrieved too.

Comment: but adding challenge in lots of page will force the user to hate my site :(

Comment: @Sourav, not necessary. StackOverflow uses this to prevent automated bots from posting and I cannot say that I hate this site.

Comment: @sourav: By challenge I don't mean something like a captcha, but a token in a hidden field which needs to be send back for the server to accept the request. It's a first line defense, but nothing prevents other people to request the page and retrieve the token.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov But i think there will be some better way !

Comment: @lkke I thought you were talking about CAPTCHA, sorry ! but in FIREFOX with WEB DEVELOPER add on user can view, modify hidden fields too !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use [cryptographic nonce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) : Typical client-server communication during a nonce-based authentication process including both a server nonce and a **client nonce** ( this client nonce could be built using the nonce recived from the server ) .

**Now this doesn't make you super secure** ( as there will be people who would be able to bypass this rather easy ) it will be harder for most floks to make a post to you're website .

[image]

( this image shows you how to use nonces in an authetification process , however you could use it for non authentification purposes )