# How do I make sure POST forms are sent through my website?

Tags: php, asp.net, authentication, post

I was wondering if there was a way to make sure a form sent through POST was from my website. I have looked at some tutorials and they suggested I use a "hidden" input value to verify, however this can quite pointless since anyone can view the html source of my website, gather information like the name attribute of the textboxes.

Let me know if I'm not being clear.

Only recently I started learning about the using PHP and ASP.NET to make websites. So, please be a little clear since I'm only a beginner. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631324/accept-post-from-only-own-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check for the referrer url, if it's matches with your domain, then it's secure.

```
$ref = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
```

Compare the value $ref with your domain name after splitting it to get only the domain name.

Comment: This is doable but I do not think `then it's secure`: because that can also be altered

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ nothing is secured in the web, but as a start up developer, this techniques could gives a positive steps on the web security.

Comment: Later part is correct, +1 for your answer :)

Comment: Referers are easily spoofed, not always sent, and overall _highly unreliable_. As easily spoofed, if not even easier, as hidden input values. If the OP asks this for _any kind of security_, `nonce`'s & the like are a lot more reliable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a technique known as Cross Site Request Forgery: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery

Essentially the practice is roughly:

- Create a big random string and store this in your server side session
- Include a hidden field in your form, which represents the random number generate above
- When you process form, check the form and session representations.
- destroy the session representation

The main limitation of this process is that your forms are time-limited, sensitive to session destruction and will only work with user interaction.

Once you've grasped the basics of PHP, why not look at using a framework? I use Symfony2 a lot and they have a nice form bundle which deals with this sort of security from the outset: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#csrf-protection

Answer (score 2):

You could also set a `$_SESSION` variable on the form page and check for it on the processing page.

Comment: ^erm.... this is the standard practice for quite a few years....

Answer (score 0):

Well you know what fields and data you are expecting from your form, so the best thing to do is validate the POST data against that. If you know you are expecting x number of fields, then validate that, and validate that data. For example, if you have a field that has a date input, use PHP to make sure it's a valid date. If it's an integer, validate that it's an integer before using it for anything. For text fields, strip all html and JavaScript, etc. You get the idea.

You're much better doing this than trying to verify that the form was posted from your website.